# NSAllowsArbitraryLoads in macOS unit test

Tags: xcode, macos, info.plist, xcode10.2

I've written a macOS app that serves up some HTTP endpoints. I'm trying to test them in a unit test, but the URLSession request returns with an error: `The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.`

So I set the plist up to allow arbitrary loads (putting aside that macOS should allow connections to localhost without HTTPS):

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

But I still get the error. Do unit tests not respect these keys?

Xcode 10.2.1, macOS 10.14.5

**Update:** It seems if I put those keys in the test target app's Info.plist, it works. But I'd call this a bug.

Comment: Maybe you need to add it in the .plist file for the test target?

Comment: Haha yeah, I *just* updated the question with that. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: I don't think it is a bug because you are running the test target, so it probably needs that in the test target plist. Just my opinion haha

Comment: I reported it as a bug to Apple, because it's the test that needs to do arbitrary loads, not the app. I can, in fact, see situations where you want to constrain what the app can do, so requiring this key in the app just for testing makes it less secure.